# How to set RotatingFileHandler for Scrapy project (or max size)

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I'm trying to make sure that logfile won't excess 1048576 bytes. Since Scrapy uses python `logging` module, I'm trying to change Scrapy's default `FileHandler` to `RotatingFileHandler`.

I couldn't find anything about this in Scrapy docs or in settings. My idea was to override `__init__()` method of spider (I have one spider).

```
def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
    self.logger.logger.root.handlers[-1] = RotatingFileHandler('log.log',maxBytes=1024,backupCount=1)
    super(MainSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
```

But scrapy logs data before spider initialization.

```
2017-10-26 13:16:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: engine_bot)
2017-10-26 13:16:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings:
....
```

Is there a way how to make this work or set maximal size of Scrapy default logfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to call [`configure_logging`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/108f8c4fd20a47bb94e010e9c6296f7ed9fdb2bd/scrapy/utils/log.py#L61) with `install_root_handler=False` as described in https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#module-scrapy.utils.log.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging


# Disable default Scrapy log settings.
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)

# Define your logging settings.
log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
log_level = logging.INFO  # Or better yet get `LOG_LEVEL` from settings.
log_file = 'log.log'  # Or better yet get `LOG_FILE` from settings.

logging.basicConfig(
    format=log_format,
    level=log_level
)

rotating_file_log = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=1024, backupCount=1)
rotating_file_log.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(log_format))

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(rotating_file_log)
```

This way you will log to console (as per the `basicConfig` default settings; though, this handler can be removed) and to rotating file(s).